# Version v8.0.0: SetImportUse()

Tags: import

Is there a bug or something?

`$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
 $mpdf->enableImports = true;
 $mpdf->debug = true;
 $mpdf->SetImportUse();`

Call to undefined method Mpdf\Mpdf::SetImportUse() in /home/.../vendor/mpdf/mpdf/src/Strict.php:15

Answer (score 8):

Found out it isn't needed in v8. In addition, importPage has different case than in v7. importPage is the correct one. So solved.

Answer (score 1):

Solution For MPDF8

```
$pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
    
#$pages array with file paths /uploads/file1.pdf, /uploads/file2.pdf...
foreach($pages as $page)    
{               
   $pagecount = $pdf->setSourceFile($page);
   $import_page = $pdf->importPage($pagecount);
   $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($import_page);
   $orientation = $size['width'] > $size['height'] ? "L" : "P";

   $pdf->AddPageByArray(['orientation' => $orientation]);
   $pdf->useTemplate($import_page);                 
}
```